# Adding a blank element to fill space?

Tags: jquery

I wasnt sure how to word this question. I am trying to figure out how I can add a blank element to fill a `.row` lets say a user creates some elements. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnpuK/).

```
 //User generates the amount of div.element (in this case there is 3)  
 <div class="row">
    <div class="element element1">Element 1</div>
    <div class="element element2">Element 2</div>
    <div class="element element3">Element 3</div>
 </div>
```

This is inside a 12 grid layout, so lets say the user wants this row to be a 4 column row (using bootstrap), you would obviously add `.span3` to each `div.element` but since it is a FOUR column layout and there is THREE `div.element` how can I add a blank element.

Keep in mind it's not just for a 4 column layout, and there is not just 3 `div.element`, another example would be keeping the 4 column layout, but say we only have 2  `div.element` then we would need to add 2 blank elements.

Take a look at the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tnpuK/) to see an example, I am thinking hard on how I would approach this but cant come up with a solution.

**Solution:** Using much help from @Trevor I came up with a good solution, it's pretty clean and functional.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9qh8S/30/). Basically I decided to keep all the elements in the first row, then improvise the amount of columns to add based on what column layout is selected, then after the desired layout is chosen the elements will be sortables which can be dragged into whichever column chosen.

Massive thanks to all who contributed and a big thanks to @Trevor.

Comment: I'm confused, what's wrong with just having `<div class="element elementx"></div>` as blank?

Comment: If the user generates say 1 element, then chooses a 4 column layout, I need 3 blank elements.. I need to write an if statement or something to say if the `index` of each element doesnt == the span column then add x amount of blank elements. Just not exactly sure how to go about that.

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tnpuK/3/

Comment: No @mattytommo its a application to build content, so the `.element` is a div created by a user, if the user selects a layout type ex. (4 column layout) and has only created one div, that div will be a part of the layout transformation along with 3 other blank divs, that can be editable. Showing the created element inside the 4 column layout. Im not sure how to write something to recognize how many elements have been created vs how many blank elements I need (here i would use `.each()` then pass index as an argument to get the numbers of existing elements) then I need to fill the blank.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle to demo a better example http://jsfiddle.net/tnpuK/8/ dont mind the span6 no-marg, thats an issue ill handle outside this question.

Comment: After the element has been added, loop over each row and grab the class names strip out just the number and add them up then subtract this from what ever you grid total is (most likely 12) and then create a new div with this size (e.g. size_2) to fill the space - if you want multiple div's to fill the space you could instead create one sized div's (size_1).

Comment: Sounds promising @MatthewRiches I kinda get what youre saying ill apply that to the fiddle, but code is much more clear in this situation than English. If you could post a working answer ill give it a 1+.. That is if you can beat me.. working on applying that now :)

Comment: Apologies for my initial confusion and your updated fiddle gave me a better idea of what you're doing, apologies again =) (Oh and good luck!)

Comment: @MackieeE no worries, I try to be clear but sometimes its hard to see exactly what I am picturing in my head, just by reading a post. Glad you understand now.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle, that is set in the right direction http://jsfiddle.net/tnpuK/10/ but the if statement is obviously not flexible with other layout types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you were getting at with the 3 div elements and the the 2 column layout. Did you want it only to show the first two columns.

Anyway here is an example that should help you get started.

```
jQuery('button.layout').click(function() {
   jQuery('.temp').remove(); // remove the temporary items
   jQuery('.item').removeClass('span3 span4'); // clean all the classes up
   var spanBlock = jQuery(this).attr('data-span')
   jQuery('.item').toggleClass(spanBlock)
   var columns = 12/parseInt(jQuery(this).data('num'));
   addColumn = columns - parseInt(jQuery('.item').length);
   for(i=0;i<addColumn;i++){
       jQuery('.row-fluid').append('<div class="item item1 temp '+spanBlock+'"></div>');    
   }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9qh8S/26/

Comment: nice this definitely looks like a huge step up, I understand the two column looked weird I need to rethink that, because usually a 2 col would have its own row im pretty sure, I may have to figure something out if a user adds three elements and wants a 2 col layout... I am thinking just keep 2 elements in the first column then the remainder in the right.. so therefore keeping 2 span6 not 4.

Comment: Yeah the for three elements the 2 column would create two rows.  However a left margin is being added to every div except the first one.  So if you wanted two rows you would have to make sure you took away the left margin for each new row.

Comment: Yeah thats what I did in an updated fiddle... I am thinking its a good idea to keep all the items inside the first span. then creating the remaining. so if there is 3 `.item` classes and then the user selects a 2 column layout all three stay inside the first span6, a new span6 is blank, then Ill use jQuery `.draggable` so the user can add whatever `.item` they want into the second span6.. does that make sense

Comment: Oh by the way I love this piece of code.. definitely giving this a green check, I am sure I can work this code into what I mentioned above.. the math used is very useful.. I may have to change it to fit the above. Id like to hear what you think about the above.

Comment: I think that sounds like a good idea for handling the 3 `.item` 2 column case.  Feel free to post another fiddle here if you have trouble pulling it off and I can take a crack at it.  Good luck!

Comment: Well its a work in progress, but here is how it should work (somewhat) http://jsfiddle.net/9qh8S/28/ I need to actually understand `for(i=0;i<addColumn;i++)` ive never used code like this, so once I understand this I think I should be set :) (i know its a counter similar in PHP, but it's a little different I kind of get it but not 100%)

Comment: Oh also looking at the console this code does `.wrapAll` each click event, I need to tweak that, and the increment (actually I think the increment is perfect I just need to fix `.wrapAll`)

Comment: Ok I found the answer http://jsfiddle.net/9qh8S/30/ this should do it for me.. thanks for getting me in the right direction.